# Allow barcode scanner to input to a read-only textbox in an ASP.net / disable default keyboards on tablets

Tags: c#, android, html, ios, asp.net

I currently have a webpage to be used on iPads / Android tablets mounted on to forklifts in a warehouse.

As of now, the webpage has a read-only textbox and a JQuery virtual keyboard, so that the user is forced to use the virtual keyboard and the tablet's automatic keyboard is disabled from popping up due to the read-only attribute.

I now have bluetooth barcode scanners that I wish to use as an alternative way to input an item number in to the read-only box. If I disable the read-only, then the tablets default keyboard pops-up, which I can't have.

So either I need the barcode scanner to be able to enter in to the read-only box, or I need to be able to always have the tablets keyboards disabled.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with bluetooth barcode scanners, but if they are like the USB ones I use, they are treated just like a keyboard. One trick we use is to track the speed in which a character is typed and accept it as "scanned" input if the rate is fast enough. A human can't type faster than a key per 15mS in my experience.

Comment: @wirecat I've thought about that, but that would require giving focus to the textbox, which would cause the tablets' keyboards to display. I have to accept the scanner input without those default keyboards coming up. Is there a way to get the input with out giving focus to an input field?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think your best bet would be to use Javascript then. This library looks promising: http://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/